# Make category parent for page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to make categories as parent for custom page.

I have custom page named PopularCategoryPage, i want to make it child for every category , url should looks like: sitename.com/%category%/popular

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the custom page , You need to set the category base from Settings-> Permalinks.

You can see the category base field from over there , set the category base as parent category and then use Custom structure from Permalink as the following ,

```
%category%/%postname%
```

Comment: But then all of my pages will have this permalink structure, but i want to do this only for this one page.

Comment: Please tell how to set the category base as parent category?